# How to extract specific data from php header response data

Tags: php

I have this data the id here (lr_01HT89SX627dFDPCAXBS4H2T9d) is dynamic.
https://www.example.com/api/pub/v2/verifications/lr_01HT89SX627dFDPCAXBS4H2T9d

I need to extract the id- lr_01HT89SX627dFDPCAXBS4H2T9d from https://www.example.com/api/pub/v2/verifications/ the id will be different for every response.

```
Header: HTTP/2 201

Header: date: Sat, 30 Mar 2024 18:26:29 GMT

Header: content-length: 0

Header: location: https://www.example.com/api/pub/v2/verifications/lr_01HT89SX627dFDPCAXBS4H2T9d

Header: cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
```

How I got the above data

```
list($headers, $content) = explode("\r\n\r\n",$result,2);
            foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $hdr)
    printf('<p>Header: %s</p>', $hdr);
echo $content;
```

I cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: Seems like you have a common URL pattern, maybe `str_contains` would be sufficient?